# Is it possible to avoid errors in parts of a c++ template function that are not going to run in the end?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have a template with two integers as input. One may have a larger type than the other. My code does a shift accordingly so the results fits the *destination type*.

Here is a basic idea of the function:

```
template<typename S, typename D>
D convert(S a)
{
     return static_cast<D>(a);
}
```

When the size between `S` and `D` changes, though, I want to shift the value. So I add a couple of conditions:

```
    if(sizeof(S) < sizeof(D))
    {
        return a << (sizeof(D) - sizeof(S)) * 8;
    }

    if(sizeof(S) > sizeof(D))
    {
        return a >> (sizeof(S) - sizeof(D)) * 8;
    }
```

The problem is that I get these errors:

> conversions.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void convert(buffer_&) [with S = unsigned char; D = short unsigned int; buffer_t = std::vector]’:
>   conversions.cpp:   required from here
>   conversions.cpp: error: right shift count >= width of type [-Werror=shift-count-overflow]
>
> ```
>   d[idx] = convert_sign<S, D>(static_cast<std::int64_t>(s[idx]) >> (sizeof(S) - sizeof(D)) * 8);
> ```

_Note: for those not understanding, the `(sizeof(S) - sizeof(D))` or `(sizeof(D) - sizeof(S))` when in the *wrong* `if()` block is going to be *negative* and thus viewed as really large as a shift parameter (since shift parameters are taken as unsigned values, it is very large and not negative, anyway the `sizeof()` returns a `std::size_t` which is unsigned.)

Obviously, I can use a pragma to ignore the warning and be done with it.

What I was expecting, though, was that the `if()` that has `false` would just not get compiled so there would no errors since that happens at compile time (i.e. the compiler knows whether the `if()` block will be executed or not at the time it gets compiled.) Is there a way to not use the pragma and still avoid the error?

Comment: have you tried with `if constexpr` ?

Comment: @max66, that does it! It compiles under C++17 with the `constexpr` there. Great! Feel free to write an answer about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I was expecting, though, was that the if() that has false would just not get compiled so there would no errors since that happens at compile time (i.e. the compiler knows whether the if() block will be executed or not at the time it gets compiled.)

You're describing the behavior of `if constexpr` that, unfortunately, is available only starting from C++17

When you write

```
if constexpr ( some_compile_time_test )
   some_code_1;
else
   some_code_2;
```

where `some_compile_time_test` is a test that can be decided compile-time (as `sizeof(S) < sizeof(D)`), the compiler compile `some_code_1` -- and completely ignore `some_code_2` -- when the test is `true` and vice versa, otherwise

If you only write

```
if ( some_test )
   some_code_1;
else
   some_code_2;
```

isn't important if the test `some_test` is deducible compile-time or not: the compiler can optimize the code ignoring the part unused but that part must be compilable.

Pre C++17 (mainly, but not only, C++11 and C++14) you have to develop **two** (or more) different functions/methods.

Look for "SFINAE" and "tag dispatching" to see a couple of useful methods.

An example of SFINAE

```
template <typename S, typename D>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(S)<sizeof(D)), S>::type convert (S a)
 { return a << (sizeof(D) - sizeof(S)) * 8; }

template <typename S, typename D>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(S)>sizeof(D)), S>::type convert (S a)
 { return a >> (sizeof(S) - sizeof(D)) * 8; }
```

and an example of tag dispatching (caution for both: code not tested)

```
template <typename S, typename D>
S convert (S a, std::true_type)
 { return a << (sizeof(D) - sizeof(S)) * 8; }

template <typename S, typename D>
S convert (S a, std::false_type)
 { return a >> (sizeof(S) - sizeof(D)) * 8; }

template <typename S, typename D>
S convert (S a)
 { return convert<S, D>(a, std::integral_constant<bool, (sizeof(S)<sizeof(D))>{}); }
```

Comment: Right, I'm sure it gets optimized properly. But to avoid the error it needs to not even compile... which happens before the optimization. For C++14 and older I'll have the diagnostic `#pragma`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke - answer improved with a couple of examples for SFINAE and tag dispatching; hope this helps.

Comment: Great, I ended up using `std::enable_if<>` because I added support for `float` and that _broke_ many things... With the SFINAE it all compiles, I just have to write _a few_ tests now to verify it is correct.